# making python 2.2 show stdout and saving to file

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm trying to write a python script that executes a bunch of other scripts. I want to make it so that when the script is run, the output of that script is displayed on the screen, but if it encounters a bad exit status, it will then take the output and append it to a log file. I was trying to use the "commands" interface, but this doesnt allow you to view the standard output AS WELL AS holding the data to be appended to a file. Please note that I'm using python 2.2 (yes, it's old but I have to work with what I'm given).

Thank you.

Sample code: (doesnt do what I want though)

```
def run_functional_analysis(script, now):
    stat, output = commands.getstatusoutput(script_dir + script + " -fb")
    if stat!=0: #If the script failed:
        os.system("echo \"[" + now + "] - " + output + "\" >> " + LOG_DIR + script + ".log")
```

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited, but does not do what I want it to do (it just copies errors to files, does not show the output simultaneously)

Comment: print output would simply print the output once the command is finished. I want it to simultaneously print while running.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.2 is quite old. You should upgrade if you can because `subprocess` is really a lot nicer than `os.system` and `os.popen`.

What you want is a file-like object that both writes to `stdout` and captures to a string (perhaps using `StringIO)`. Then you can specify that object as `stdout` and `stderr` in your `subprocess` calls.

```
import sys, subprocess
from cStringIO import StringIO

class Outcap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = StringIO()
    def write(self, data):
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        self.output.write(data)
    def flush(self):
        sys.stdout.flush(data)
    def close(self):
        pass

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self.output.getvalue()

outcap = Outcap()

try:
    subprocess.check_call("foo bar baz".split(), stdout=outcap, stderr=outcap)
    subprocess.check_call("one two three".split(), stdout=outcap, stderr=outcap)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    outcap.write("return code: %s\n", e.returncode)
    open("log.txt", "w").write(outcap.text)
```

If you can't upgrade your Python, but you're on Linux, another option is to handle it outside of Python by piping the commands you're running through `tee` command.

```
your command goes here 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

This will save all output of your command to `log.txt` as well as sending it to standard out. What you choose to do with it from there is up to your Python script. You could, for example, log to a temporary file and move it to a permanent location only if one of the commands fails.

Comment: Wow, I just realized that python 2.2 doesn't even have subprocess. I thought it had a very minimal version of it. Do you have any hints to doing this without subprocess? I'll make an edit above.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote all that before realizing that Python 2.2 didn't have `subprocess`. I put an alternative in there.

Comment: So I tried that, and I get an error that says:

grep: writing output: Broken pipe

Comment: That's a shell error; hard to say what's causing it without seeing what exact command line you're ending up executing.

Comment: If I try to run that command on the shell (without python), I get an error that says "Ambiguous Output Redirect". Is that related to the script? Edit: I think I might know what the issue is, but I could be wrong. My shell type is apparently csh. So I'm sure that if I execute things through python, it is also doing it in csh. So it may not recognize the redirection above.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is a bashism. You could try executing it with `bash -c` if you have bash installed.

Comment: What I did instead is made a bash script and passed the script and log name as arguments. Still gives me the broken pipe error. I know that the script uses a lot of grep, but it works perfectly fine without the redirection above. Do you have any idea why doing the above redirection will break grep?

Comment: Hard to guess, maybe you could play with it from the command line doing various kinds of redirections and see what it doesn't like.